# Setting disable attribute for a button in html works if i set it inside html file but not when i try to use the common javascript file

Tags: jquery, html

I am workin on a web app with lots of similar screens. It has a save button. I want it disabled by default. When there is some change in it should become enabled. I was able to work it with jquery.

I have the button with same name in all screens and so I have created a common javascript file which i include in all the html file.

When I try to set up the disable attribute in each file with it works.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSave').attr("disabled", true);
});    
</script>
```

Then I have jquery code in common js file to enable that button if any change is seen.

```
var button = $('#btnSave');
$('form :input').bind('keyup change', function () {

    // get all that inputs that has changed
    var changed = $('form :input').not(button).filter(function () {
        if (this.type == 'radio' || this.type == 'checkbox') {
            return this.checked != $(this).data('default');
        } else {
            return this.value != $(this).data('default');
        }
    });
    // disable if none have changed - else enable if at least one has changed
    $('#btnSave').prop('disabled', !changed.length);
});
```

But when I try to do the same in the common js file with this it works for some screens but not for others. Just wondering why is this happenning ? It opens the form with the save enabled instead of disabled as I would have wanted.

```
$('#btnSave').attr("disabled", true);
var button = $('#btnSave');
$('form :input').bind('keyup change', function () {

    // get all that inputs that has changed
    var changed = $('form :input').not(button).filter(function () {
        if (this.type == 'radio' || this.type == 'checkbox') {
            return this.checked != $(this).data('default');
        } else {
            return this.value != $(this).data('default');
        }
    });
    // disable if none have changed - else enable if at least one has changed
    $('#btnSave').prop('disabled', !changed.length);
});
```

Comment: use $('#btnSave').attr("disabled", "disabled"); instead

Comment: @MichielReyers No. As of jQuery 1.6 `.attr()` shouldn't be used for modifying properties.

Comment: Mmmm, some studying to do for me I guess, thanks for pointing this out.